# How do I retrieve values from a dictionary if the keys matched to it are the same on a different dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm not sure how to do it. I tried it below, but it didn't work, as you might expect. I'm attempting to create an ordering software in which a user orders food using the same keys as in order_menu and it is added to order_dictionary.  Then, using the keys on the list, I calculate and add the order price using the values from order menu.

```
order_menu = {("C", "Chips (Scoops)") : 2.80, ("F", "Fish (Battered)") : 2.90, ("Fc", "Fish (Crumbed)") : 4.90, ("Fib", "Filet (Battered)") : 6.90, ("Fic", "Filet (Crumbed)") : 6.90, 
     ("Hd", "Hot Dog") : 2.60, ("S", "Sausage") : 2.60, ("Mp" , "Meat Patty (Homemade)") : 3.90, ("Cr", "Crabstick") : 2.50, ("Sr", "Spring Roll (Homemade)") : 2.80, 
     ("Cr", "Curry Roll (Homemade)"): 2.80, ("Pof", "Potato Fritter (Homemade)") : 1.20, ("Paf", "Paua Fritter (Homemade)") : 5.90, ("Cn", "Chicken Nugget") : 1, 
     ("Mh", "Mini Hot Dog (On a stick)") : 1.20, ("Pf", "Pineapple Fritter") : 2.50}
order_dictionary = {"C", "Hot Dog", "Chicken Nugget", "S"}

    for food, values in order_menu.items():
            if food in order_dictionary:
                    print(values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI in your code `order_dictionary` is not a dictionary, it is a *set*.

The problem you have currently is the keys in `order_menu` are tuples - a pair of values.

So you need something like:

```py
menu = {("C", "Chips (Scoops)") : 2.80, ("F", "Fish (Battered)") : 2.90, ("Fc", "Fish (Crumbed)") : 4.90, ("Fib", "Filet (Battered)") : 6.90, ("Fic", "Filet (Crumbed)") : 6.90, 
     ("Hd", "Hot Dog") : 2.60, ("S", "Sausage") : 2.60, ("Mp" , "Meat Patty (Homemade)") : 3.90, ("Cr", "Crabstick") : 2.50, ("Sr", "Spring Roll (Homemade)") : 2.80, 
     ("Cr", "Curry Roll (Homemade)"): 2.80, ("Pof", "Potato Fritter (Homemade)") : 1.20, ("Paf", "Paua Fritter (Homemade)") : 5.90, ("Cn", "Chicken Nugget") : 1, 
     ("Mh", "Mini Hot Dog (On a stick)") : 1.20, ("Pf", "Pineapple Fritter") : 2.50}
order_keys = {"C", "Hot Dog", "Chicken Nugget", "S"}

for food, values in menu.items():
    if food[0] in order_keys:
        print(values)
```

Another way would be to 'unpack' the tuple already in your for loop like this:

```py
for (food_key, food_name), values in menu.items():
    if food_key in order_keys:
        print(values)
```